# I need to access variable inside a function using a global variable (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have declared a variable as global and I need to access a value inside a function using this global variable.

I have tried this in many ways but it is not working.

How is this possible?
*Go through my code in below*

### I need to get value of 'savedvalue' which is inside future function 'saveddata', in value1(gobal varable)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  final inputtext = TextEditingController();
  String? value1;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 300,
          child: Column(children: [
            TextField(
              controller: inputtext,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(), label: Text('Enter your name')),
            ),
            ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  savedata(context);
                  // print(value1);
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                label: Text('click Here'))
          ]),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }

  Future<void> savedata(BuildContext context) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('Name', inputtext.text);
    final savedValue = prefs.getString('Name');

    print(savedValue);
    // value1=savedValue.toString();
    if (savedValue == 'jibi') {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('Screen_2');
      // print('Working');
    }
    this.value1 = savedValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: You try pass `value1` as parameter of method `savedata(value1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function `savedata` is asynchronous but `onPressed` is not, hence `print(value1)` may execute before `savedata` is completed.

try:

```
onPressed: () async {
  await savedata(context);
  print(value1);
},
```